# "Join Attributes By Nearest" in QGIS Graphical Modeler Shifts Attribute Field Order

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-modeler

I am using the QGIS Graphical Modeler to sample a DEM using two created point features (road & pipeline) then use a spatial join to find the three closest road locations to a pipe location.  The output of the sampled features are as expected, but when I try and use the 'Join By Nearest' tool in the Graphical Modeler to find the closest sampled road locations to sampled pipeline points, it shifts the joined column data of input layer 2 (road) to the right one spot.

However, when I do this same process manually it works out ok.

[image: Pipe raster sampled attribute table]

[image: Road raster sampled attribute table]

[image: Join By Nearest dialogue box]

[image: Resulting 'joined' attribute table]

[image]

Comment: If you find no other way, you can use Refactor fields to rearrange the order